# SQL server, is there any central table to get meta data of all tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have to query in SQL server about which table is having maximum data and which one is having minimum data.

Please tell me how can i do this..

i am runninf SQL server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for metadata **about** the data structures, use:

```
select * from sys.objects
select * from sys.columns
```

Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: Or sys.tables, for the tables specifically (sys.objects contains everything.....)

Comment: @Marc you are correct. Force of habit; I usually start with sys.objects but sys.tables would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) you can run it in a loop over all your tables

If you would like to get space usage for all tables you could run (the undocumented shortcut):

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
    [name] NVARCHAR(128),
    [rows] CHAR(11),
    reserved VARCHAR(18), 
    data VARCHAR(18), 
    index_size VARCHAR(18),
    unused VARCHAR(18)
) 

INSERT #t
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''?'',''TRUE'' '
```

Then search through #t for your results

Comment: I guess you got more out of the OP's question than I did. +1 for pointing out a stored proc I don't think I've used before.

Comment: @Tim ... its kind of hard to tell what he means by "maximum data" ... it could be "most rows", "total storage without indexes" or "total storage" and more ... it should be clarified

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that returns the number of pages in all data structures for each table in current database:

```
select object_name([object_id]) as obj_name, sum(page_count) as page_num
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
group by [object_id]
order by sum(page_count) desc
```

[Dynamic management views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) provide lots of data about the database.